# How to create Highcharts pareto with drilldown

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, pareto-chart

I want to create a pareto with drilldown. I'm able to create the drilldown, but the pareto line doesn't appear on the graph. Is there a demo of how to do this so that I can use that as an example?

This in an example of the code that I wrote, the drilldown works, but the pareto line doesn't appear.

```
series: [
            {
            type: 'pareto',
            name: 'Pareto',
            yAxis: 1,
            zIndex: 10,
            color: 'orange',
            baseSeries: 1,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2,
                valueSuffix: '%'
         
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Example',
            type: 'column',
            data: [{}
  
                <?php foreach($Example1 as $m => $a): ?>
                ,{
                    name: '<?php echo $m ?>',
                    y: <?php echo $a['Qty'] ?>,
                    drilldown: '<?php echo $m ?>'
                }
                <?php endforeach ?>
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'center',
                format: '{point.y}',
                style: {
                    color: 'white',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                }
            }
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{}            

                <?php foreach ($Example1 as $m => $a): ?>
                ,{
                    name: '<?php echo $m ?>',
                    id: '<?php echo $m ?>',
                    data: [
                        <?php foreach ($Example2 as $r): ?>
                        <?php if ($r['Example'] == $m): ?>
                        ['<?php echo $r['ExampleExample'] ?>', <?php echo $r['Qty'] ?>],
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    ]
                }
                <?php endforeach ?>
            ]
```

Comment: After drill up you want to see the pareto series for that series you enter, and now you see only on the main. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, I want to see the pareto line for the main and after drilldown. It doesn't appear on the main or after drilldown.

Comment: Solution with working pareto series linked to main series --> [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5qvmw4p/1/). I'm not sure that series works after drilldown, I will check.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Thanks, how can you make it show the label's names instead of numbers for every column?

Comment: Add to options `xAxis.type: 'category'`

Comment: @SebastianHajdus I've tried that, but when I add xAxis.type: 'category', if I click on a column on main and then go back to main, a number of new columns appear. That also happens if I add that to your example.

Comment: It's look like after returning to the main series, pareto doesn't match the category on xAxis it's a bug I will report this. Other things inside drilldown.series it is not possible to set the pareto series that functionallity was not implemented with drilldown.